# Moving two MS Excel cells that depend on each other

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table where I enter the qualification times manually `Name` and `Timer`. It calulates the Final Time automatically, but I want it to sort the Final Time and Name in the right side from the fastest to the slowest, as in the second image.  I tried using VLOOKUP and INDEX, but didn't manage to get it. I need help finding the right formulas to Cells I$ and J$. I hope to get a answer from here.

[image: Image 1]

Hope to get it like following:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula in your column J. Enter it in J3 and copy down. As you see, it refers to column H where it expects the numbers 1 and up. So, it will look for the smallest, second smallest etc values in the given range.

`=SMALL($D$3:$D$6,H3)`

In I3 please enter the formula below and copy down.

`=INDEX($B$3:$B$6,MATCH(J3,$D$3:$D$6,0))`

It looks for the value the SMALL function extracted and finds the matching name.

Comment: Thanks. If someone else finds this too, remember to check (probably because location?) formulas are used. For me I have to use a semicolon rather than a comma in the functions.